# Leitura de aquivo .xlsm (Excel) apartir do meu aplicativo

Tags: ios, objective-c, microsoft-excel, iphone, swift

Como leio um arquivo `.xlsm` (planilha do Excel) a partir do meu aplicativo?

Basicamente eu preciso obter os dados desta planilha. Pegar o valor de cada uma das células que esta possui.

Há alguma coisa nativa para eu poder efetuar esta leitura? Alguma biblioteca para indicação? Em caso de exemplo, pode ser em `Objective-C` ou `Swift`.

Answer (score 1):

Existem dois projetos para se trabalhar com arquivos Excel em Objective-C.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/libxls/ e https://github.com/dhoerl/DHlibxls (Interface para o primeiro)

Answer (score 0):

Se possível, converta o arquivo xls para csv. O próprio excel faz isso.
Depois pode utilizar essa biblioteca para ler o arquivo. https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser